# Singleton classes serializable

Tags: java, object, serialization, singleton, effective-java

Can anyone explain this paragraph: [copied from Effective Java Joshua Bloch 3rd edition Chapter 2 Item 3 ]

To  make    a   singleton   class   that    uses    either  of  these   approaches (i.e. keeping    the constructor private and exporting   a   public  static  member  to  provide access  to  the sole    instance)   serializable ,  it  is  not sufficient  merely  to  add implements  Serializable to its declaration.    To  maintain    the singleton   guarantee,  declare all instance    fields transient    and provide a   readResolve method. Otherwise,  each time   a   serialized  instance    is  deserialized,   a   new instance    will    be  created,    leading, in the case    of  our example,    to  spurious    Elvis   sightings.  To  prevent this    from happening, add this    readResolve method  to  the Elvis   class:

```
//  readResolve method  to  preserve    singleton   property 
private Object  readResolve()   
{ 
//  Return  the one true    Elvis   and let the garbage collector //    take    care    of  the Elvis   impersonator. 
return  INSTANCE; 
}
```

Comment: When deserializing, instead of returning a new instance, it will return the single instance INSTANCE to be singleton-compliant.

Comment: The paragraph explains the issue, and solution fairly well.  What exactly is the point (or points) which you find unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using serialization/deserializaiton we can create many objects which leads to singleton failure. So to avoid this we have to 
implement the readResolve() method.
During deserializaiton, Before giving the deserialized object it will check the readResolve() method. 
If you override and give your singleton instance then no new object will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this scenario, your application runs and serializes the Singleton (refer as s1 from now on). Over the weekend the application is torn down and restarted. A new singleton is created when the process comes up (now is s2). While the application is running using s2 another object deserializes s1. You now have two singletons which are different objects living in the same application.

Hope this helps.